# Документация по созданию Api сайта

Tags: документация

Нужно создать api для сайта, чтобы подружить с ним приложение андроид, но как это сделать пока что очень плохо представляю. Есть ли какой-нить мануал по этому делу? Или все зависит от конкретной задачи, от движка сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретного рецепта "как сделать апи" нет. Есть общие практики:

- [REST](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) - создаем ресурсы, для каждого ресурса получаем url типа /video/comments, для каждого url определяем какие из CRUD методов доступны и какие параметры для этого необходимы. После этого по типу запроса - PUT GET POST DELETE (соответсвенно аналогам из CRUD) определяется действие, которое должно быть выполнено с ресурсом. Получается следующая ситуация:

  ```
  GET /video/comments?id=12345&sort=reverse - получить комментарии к видео с идентификатором 12345 в обратном порядке. Также более естественным может быть вариант с урлом типа /video/12345/comments?sort=reverse
  PUT /video?title=Supertitle - создать видео из загруженного файла и задать ему имя Supertitle
  и т.д.
  ```
- Простой GET/POST и т.н. методы - урлы, каждый из которых отвечает за свое действие. Фактически это простой проброс функций "наружу". Типичный пример - вконтакте:

  ```
  http://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1,2,3
  http://api.vk.com/method/wall.get...
  ```

REST будет хорош тем, что он хоть в полуавтоматическом режиме, но описывается, и засунуть в другое приложение схему становится легче. Однако если это апи для единственного приложения, то на это можно наплевать. Самое главное - жэто расписать что и в каком формате должен отдавать сервис, как информация должна подписываться, чтобы интерфейс появился и был утвержден хотя бы в начальном варианте до написания этой апишки, потому что иначе это дело превратится в трудноподдерживаемый разносол. Ну и в качестве веселой байки - у меня однажды случился скандал по поводу использования мд5-подписей, пушо с самого начала надо было стандарт использвания писать.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!